# What are the 40,000 destinations that the Eurail Global Pass is giving access to? Train stations? Cities? Something else?

Tags: trains, europe, interrail, eurail

I read on https://www.eurail.com/en/eurail-passes:

> Eurail Global Pass: Travel to over 40,000 destinations in 33 countries with our classic Pass, delivered straight to your device.

What are the 40,000 destinations that the Eurail Global Pass is giving access to? That sounds like a lot. I wonder how they obtained that number.

Comment: The number of train stations in Europe? Should be on the same order of magnitude

Comment: The Netherlands claims 399 stations alone. Seems a reasonable order of magnitude…

Comment: The page you linked to shows the 33 countries.  Are you after someone to type out every station in each of those countries?

Comment: @Doc no, I'm trying to understand what they mean by destination. Train stations? Cities? Etc. I wonder how they obtained that number.

Comment: The number of places accessible by rail? Looks about right regarding order of magnitude. I am perfectly willing to believe there are 40000 places in Europe with rail access.

Comment: @KristvanBesien thanks, what are these 40000 places in Europe with rail access? Train stations? Cities? Etc. I wonder how they obtained that number.

Comment: @KristvanBesien: But aren't there also 50000 places in Europe with rail access? I usually take the train (and walk) to and home from work, does that make our office and my apartment (I wouldn't categorise either as tourist destinations) accessible by rail?

Comment: It's marketing babble which typically doesn't use well grafted definitions :-).

Comment: If you're willing to write a scraper, you can find the full list [via this API](https://api.timetable.eurail.com/v2/locations?input=a&results=100).

Answer (score 12):

[This Kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/headsortails/train-stations-in-europe) lists over 36,000 train stations across Europe, so yes, it's likely that **the "destinations" are mostly train stations**.  Which makes sense, because Eurail is a train pass and is largely limited to trains.

As for why 36,000 vs 40,000, it's not entirely straightforward to define a "train station".  Do subways count? Tram stops? Cable cars? Funiculars? Cargo sidings?  The answer will depend on what you include and exclude.

Comment: Interesting to note that in that dataset, 35% of the “stations” are in Switzerland. Probably means different definitions of what should be included or not and possibly explains the gap between 36k and 40k. For CH it looks like many bus stops are included (though not all).

Comment: Many buses in Switzerland are run by rail companies, not all. Same happens in France, if not as often.

Comment: And the borders of what Eurail includes may well differ from what the dataset includes.

Comment: @Willeke there are bus stops in the suburbs of Basel, operated by BLT, one of the two tram/bus operators in there. Like a stop every few hundred meters. Ditto for La Chaux de Fonds. Switzerland is special because most local public transport is included in nationwide travel cards. Not sure those would be covered by Eurail?

Comment: Train stations in European Russia are not covered by EUrail, and there are quite many of those.

Comment: @gerrit The data set is from a retailer of EU train tickets, and they state it contains only "a few" Russian train stations, likely those that have (had) international services to the EU.

Answer (score 4):

The [Eurail booking engine](https://www.eurail.com/en/book-reservations#/) does include not only train stations, but many local bus stops, especially in Switzerland (where some of the services around Basel or in La-Chaux-de-Fonds are included, for instance).

This will depend a lot on the [participating "railway" companies](https://www.eurail.com/en/get-inspired/trains-europe/useful-train-information/participating-railway-companies), which are in some cases just local public transport operators.

The list above contains most of the operators, but for Switzerland there are so many that they split out most on [this separate page](https://www.eurail.com/en/get-inspired/top-destinations/switzerland-train/swiss-railway-companies-included). Note the presence of BLT (operator of trams and buses in Basel suburbs), TRN (ditto for Neuchâtel canton), or TPF (Fribourg). There are more operators where you only get a discount rather than free rides [here](https://www.eurail.com/en/get-inspired/top-destinations/switzerland-train/swiss-railway-companies-discounted).

So you will probably find hundreds of "destinations" for Basel, dozens for cities such as La Chaux de Fonds or Neuchatel, and so on.

The database linked to in [lambshaanxy's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/178693/30703) which has 36000 destinations seems very similar, and 35% of the "stations" in that dataset are in Switzerland, due to the inclusion of many local operators, which results in dozens of bus stops a few hundred meters apart to be listed.

Note that you **can** actually travel free of charge to many of those "destinations", but whether "Biel-Benken Kirchgasse" and "Biel-Benken Bruëcke" 300 meters down the road can be considered different "destinations" is for you to judge...

On the other hand, there are many "regional" bus services which are included which probably make actual sense.
I'm actually surprised that SNCF (the french national railway company) operates buses to small villages that have never seen a train in their life, when I thought they had only replaced some railways with bus lines.